# How to know whether the my address received ERC20Tokens?

Tags: transactions, web3.py

This is my transaction id : `0xe2a18a18180d960061611c27ced38b965b445a6263a54b1495abf27b9ce1d628`

I am getting the transaction details using **web3**

```
w3.eth.getTransaction('0xe2a18a18180d960061611c27ced38b965b445a6263a54b1495abf27b9ce1d628')
```

The output is

```
 AttributeDict({
'blockHash':'0xd3c702edb585f8e041e2873d94582af7bb2a0e249ca8b0e2300eb2a22188cdf0', 'blockNumber': 5547769, 'chainId': None, 'condition': None, 'creates': None, 'from': '0x478a2bC9Fa2Bc594d875BC9c88F5cE9626BFc8C4', 'gas': 250000, 'gasPrice': 100000000000, 'hash': '0xe2a18a18180d960061611c27ced38b965b445a6263a54b1495abf27b9ce1d628', 'input': '0x338b5dea000000000000000000000000bbff862d906e348e9946bfb2132ecb157da3d4b400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000084b72cd39af114f0000', 'nonce': 578, 'publicKey': '0xca81754e8977cfede27801ea7170c3581f4ec85b6f218130a7c0d8bbc1e86775a35e912115ff64ab01cb6402da66edf222b2a63f2b1ffb091f3595b74c5c47f6', 'r': '0x593cfc25f4860ec2ad60d9ecbf3c5af1b00d5151f85d8e06e8f7547236cc3d3d', 'raw': '0xf8ac82024285174876e8008303d090942a0c0dbecc7e4d658f48e01e3fa353f44050c20880b844338b5dea000000000000000000000000bbff862d906e348e9946bfb2132ecb157da3d4b400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000084b72cd39af114f00001ca0593cfc25f4860ec2ad60d9ecbf3c5af1b00d5151f85d8e06e8f7547236cc3d3da008cd57f41ab781f36d54664e7f0b0d0902593c53f054532e6e46ba5c65816684', 's': '0x8cd57f41ab781f36d54664e7f0b0d0902593c53f054532e6e46ba5c65816684', 'standardV': '0x1', 'to': '0x2a0c0DBEcC7E4D658f48E01e3fA353F44050c208', 'transactionIndex': 0, 'v': '0x1c', 'value': 0})
```

The above transaction is a token transfer. I want to know the token details ( contract address) from the above raw transaction. I can't find any contract address to know about the token details. How to find out the what token is involved in the above raw transaction? Could anyone explain?

Comment: If you send the tx to contract the address in `to`  is contract address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check balance on etherscan, MEW, Metamask on any XYZ wallet.

But it seems you are more concerned about knowing the contract address from tx Hash. You can then programmatically check the balance or transaction details.

**Whenever you call a contract function, to `to` param in Tx receipt is the contract address.** You can use this address to fetch contract details if you have ABI.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is check in MetaMask if it detects any tokens on your address.

Go to `Token` > `Add Token`, then give the address of your token contract and the rest should fill automatically. Then you can see your balance in that token.

Answer (score 0):

I use etherscan.io. I use MEW but don't like to login unless I have to especially after [recent events](https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/24/myetherwallet-hit-by-dns-attack/)

Here is a [screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/abhle4Qc1B) of the address you provided on [image: etherscan.io] 
I can see that there was some "sharder token" transferred. Is that what you are expecting to see?

Comment: I can't see the screenshot. Could you please upload it again?

Comment: Apologies I understand, there is a link hardcoded under "screensot"

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/abhle4Qc1B

Comment: An answer should not contain a question, use comments for that.